# In case of S3, Does Spark -3.x read only the filtered data from file formats like parquet instead of loading the whole file in memory

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, apache-spark-sql, parquet, apache-spark-dataset

In the case of loading/reading parquet file from S3, Does spark 3.X load the complete file in memory and then perform filtration or it loads the filtered data as it does in the case of Hadoop?

Answer (score 1):

It loads and seeks around, but if you are using the s3a connector and hadoop-2.7 binaries which many spark releases are bundled with, that seek() is implemented by breaking any existing GET Request and then doing another GET from the new seek location to the EOF again. This is very inefficient for seek-heavy code; hadoop-2.8+ lets you switch to random IO (fs.s3a.experimental.fadvise random).

Tip: for Hadoop 2.8+, call toString() on the FSDataInputStream you have and you'll get a statistics report from s3a and abfs connectors telling you bytes read, bytes discarded, etc.